# Color of the highlight of the found word is too faint to see in Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, find, highlighting, replacement

When I use the "Find and Replace" feature, the word that has been found is highlighted in a very faint gray such that I can't see it very well.

How can I change the default color that MS Word uses to highlight the word that it found?

My steps are:

1. open the Word doc
2. Ctrl + F
3. select "Advanced Find" in the pull-down menu in the navigation pane on the left
4. click the "Replace" tab
5. type a word in each of the "Find what:" and "Replace with:" fields
6. click "Find Next"

The last step is the problem because it finds and highlights the word, but I want to change the color that Word uses to highlight the found word.

Comment: Are you using a background in Office?  I use No Background and colorful for borders. Highlights show up fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in MS Word.  There is however a registry edit that's been circulating online for many years that still works.  This will allow toggling the highlight color of selected text between gray and black using the value of the `NoTranslucentSelection` DWORD between 1 for black, and 0 for gray (default).

**Text Selection Highlight:   `=0`  vs.  `=1`**
[image]  [image]

#### Warning about Registry Edits

Standard registry edit warning provided by Microsoft:

> **Warning:** Exercise extreme caution when using the Registry Editor. If you edit the registry incorrectly, serious problems might occur that could require a complete reinstall of the operating system and result in data loss. Avoid any edits suggested by unofficial sources.  For added protection, before making edits based on officially published Microsoft documentation, be sure to back up the registry. Then you can restore it if a problem occurs. For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692).

Spoiler for experienced users:

> `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options`
> `DWORD (32-bit) Value { Value name: "NoTranslucentSelection",`
>                                             `Value data: "0" }`

#### Steps to Edit Registry

1. Open the Windows Registry Editor:
   <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type `regedit` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
   [image]
2. You will then need to click <kbd>YES</kbd> when asked if you want to make changes to your device.
3. In the Registry Editor, enter the following path:
   `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office`
   [image]
4. Then select the key for the **current version** of MS Office,  `16.0` in my example, and navigate to its child `Word`, and that key's child `Options`.
   If we have the same version of Office, your address would now be:
    `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options`
   [image]
5. If it doesn't exist, create a new DWORD for `NoTranslucentSelection` in `Options`:

   1. Right-mouse click on `Options`
   2. Hover over `New   >`
   3. Select `DWORD (32-bit) Value` from the list
      [image]
   4. Paste `NoTranslucentSelection` in place of the default name `New Value #1` (no spaces, preceding, inside, or following the string). 
      [image]
      If the default name is saved before you get the chance to edit it, simply right-click on it and select `Rename` from the menu.
      [image]
6. Right-click on `NoTranslucentSelection` and set the `Value data:` field to `1`, then click <kbd>OK</kbd>
   [image]
7. Make sure that all MS Office applications and services have been exited or restarted
   This last step is very important.  In my case, the changes to `NoTranslucentSelection` (`1` to `0` and `0` to `1`) did not take effect unless I exited all Office applications and services including restarting the `Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service`. 
   [image]
   **You could also simply restart your PC if you prefer.**

---

<sub>**Text Selection Highlight *(Enabled)***</sub>
[image]
<sub>**Registry Setting *(Enabled)***</sub>
[image]

---

<sub>**Text Selection Highlight  *(Disabled)***</sub>
[image]
<sub>**Registry Setting *(Disabled)***</sub>

[image]